# How to connect an Android App directly with MS SQLServer 2008

Tags: android, sql-server

I'm doing a test application to connect directly to a MS SqlServer 2008, but I need some help to know if my code is wrong or I can't do that connection directly.

What happen is, I use a TextView just to show me a Value that is inserted on the DataBase Table, but that won't happen and just appear the "Hello World" message, when I start the application.

I'm using the jTDS driver 1.2.5, but already used the 1.2.7 and 1.3.1 but they not showed any results.

Follow the code, below.

```
        // Connection with DataBase (SQL SERVER 2008)//

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection conn = null;
    String ConnURL = null;
    String data;
    TextView textView;
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtData);


    try {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.0.169:1433/ANDROID_SQL;username=sa;password=@dm1n102030;instance=MEGACONTROL";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from usuarios");
        resultSet.next();
        data = resultSet.getString("nome");
        textView.setText(data);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you dont get any errors.. try running a trace in SQL server profiler and see if a request is made.

Comment: @JeffUK, and how I do this?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650699.aspx